# The perfect heatmap

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Forget about these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just found the perfect one. Can you explain why I think the below heatmap is perfect?

[image]

---

<sub>Sad Side Note: There would be a perfect xkcd title in [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/monthly-topic-challenge-1-restricted-title-xkcd-1xxx), but that would just completely give away the solution :/</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree that it's perfect!

Each of the first three heatmaps

> corresponds to a keyboard layout:
>  [image: images from puzzle, labelled with letters]
>
>  The first is the well-known QWERTY layout, and the others are the Dvorak and Colemak keyboards. Each letter's color is based on its frequency in English-language usage.
>
>  (As you can see, in the second and third, the middle row is much more intense than the other two rows - this is a proposed benefit of Dvorak and Colemak, since they don't require you to move your hands off of the home row as often.)

The last one

> [image: image from puzzle, labelled with letters spelling MR JOCK...]
>
>  instead spells `Mr. Jock, TV quiz PhD, bags few lynx` - a well-known [*perfect pangram*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram#Perfect_pangrams)!

Comment: "i'm gonna teach my kids to shun the Qwerty keyboard layout, and instead use the much-superior Mr Jock layout".